# how to fetch users after getting response after $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
{
        $lookup: {
          from: 'comments',
          let: {
            p_id: '$_id'
          },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $eq: ['$post_id', '$$p_id']
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          as: 'comments'
        }
      },
        $unwind: '$comments',
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: '$comments.sender_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'commented_user'
        }
      },
```

I am trying to fetch users those comments from another collection, I do not understand when does comments will accessible to use please guide on this thanks

Comment: If you could give sample documents in your comments and users collections it would be helpful

Comment: in comments : _id, text, sender_id, date
in users : _id, name, password, timestamp

Comment: use $unwind to convert result into Array as $lookup will return `[object]`

Comment: @Shivam if possible then add schema or your approach to question by editting.

Comment: Updated code please take a look now

Comment: What result do you get?